# When do we say a function $p$ depends on time?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Suppose I have a function:

$$
p=3\cdot (x(t))^{2/3}
$$

In that function, $x$ depends on time $t$, but do we say in our notation that $p$ depends on $t$, or just on $x$? Specifically, we require that $p$ is globally Lipschitz with respect to $x$ and piecewise continuous with respect to $t$. **Question**: in the above function, is there any point of checking if $p$ is piecewise continuous with respect to $t$? Or is that needed only for function that are explicitly dependent on $t$, such that $g=3\cdot (x(t))^{2/3}\cdot t^2$?

Thank you!